# Why does this Regular Expression not match anything?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use the following regular expression to find all e-mails in an html string:

```
RegExp
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}

HTML
<a href="mailto:ddawson@gcitravel.net">ddawson@gcitravel.net</a></span>. </p>
```

I'm using matcher.find() which is supposed to find substrings is it not? When I perform the search it is coming up empty, any ideas why?

Comment: Is A-Z only matching upper case?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but I'd recommend changing the end of your regex to `{2,6}`, given the newer, longer TLDs (`.museum`, `.berlin`, etc).

Comment: Ahah! Thank you ver much sir.

Comment: Please check my answer at the bottom, this regexp is still incorrect. It will not find co.uk, de.com and it's still too short for root domain .international.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is case sensitive by default so for instance last part `.net` can't be matched with `.[A-Z]{2,4}`.

To make your regex case insensitive add `(?i)` flag

```
"(?i)[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}"
```

or compile it with `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag.

```
Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake >.<

Comment: @user2774147 Happens to the best :)

Answer (score 2):

`A-Z` will only match upper case, and there is an extra `\`. Try this...

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

Comment: The extra backslash was undoubtedly because this is Java and he had to double it to get it to work in a string literal.  So it was probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

This way of searching for emails is no longer correct when we have new domains. This regular expression would not find any email in domain [site.berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.berlin). Extend 2,4, delete or look for

```
[A-Za-z0-9-+/.]*@[A-Za-z0-9/.-]*\\.*[A-Za-z]$
```

I don't have enough reputation to comment a post, afair the longest TLD domain is .international so {2,4} won't find it and remember about domains with dot inside root name like .co.uk, .de.com. Domain must also end with a letter, it cannot be number or special character. Email address might contain [delimiter](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter) like + or -